# PHPUnit object initialized in setUp() becomes null after 1st test

Tags: phpunit

I am new to PHPunit and while learning it with sample classes, I am getting error. The error is that, the Object `$this->sysman`, that is initialized in `setUp()` becomes null after execution of the 1st test. Below is code, which I am trying. Please let me know what is mistake here. Thanks.

```
class PersonTest extends TestCase {

/** @var SysManService $sysman */
protected $sysman;
protected $personModel;

public function setUp(){
    /** @var Adapter $adapter */
    $adapter = $this->prophesize(Adapter::class)->reveal();

    /** @var LoggerService $logger */
    $logger = $this->prophesize(LoggerService::class)->reveal();

    /** @var  ContainerInterface $container */
    $container = $this->prophesize(ContainerInterface::class);
    $config = (array)$container->get('config');

    $this->sysman = new SysManService($adapter, $logger, $config);
    //$sysman = new SysManService($adapter, $logger, $config);

    $this->personModel = new Person($this->sysman);
  }

protected function tearDown(){ }

public function testPropertyUserNameExists() {
    $this->assertObjectHasAttribute('userName', $this->personModel);
}

public function testPropertyPasswordExists() {
    $this->assertObjectHasAttribute('password', $this->personModel);
}}
```

Comment: What exactly does the error say? Which object is `null`? The idea of the `setUp` function is that it runs before every single test. So even if one of the tests would set an object to `null`, the second test should start with a new run. Also you are mocking the container and then calling the `get` function on it. This is useless since it will always return `null` in this case. Which means your `$config` is an empty array. You're also initializing 2 objects in a unit test which I wouldn't recommend. If this is a test for the Person object, just stick with that and mock only the Sysman object.

Comment: Thanks for input.  The `$this->sysman`  passed to `Person` becomes null after first test. So the second test is failing. I am getting data for  `$config` through container. It is fine, even it is null.  But I am not understanding why `$this->sysman`   is becoming null.  Also please suggest how do i make changes as per your last 2 statements. Which 2 object i am initializing?

Comment: You are making a `new` instance of sysManService. You could just do `$this->sysman = $this->prophesize(SysManService::class)`. This way you dont have to mock the adapter, logger and container/config. I'm not sure if that will also solve your problem with the object becoming null, it shouldn't do that in the first place. But it is a good place to start.

Comment: I tried, but got another error involving object type.  Error is `Argument 1 passed to Testbed\Model\Person::__construct() must be an instance of App\Service\SysManService, instance of Prophecy\Prophecy\MethodProphecy given`